# Ways to track an employees hours in redis - what was useful? - what wasn't?

Tags: database, redis

I'm setting up a simple punch in, punch out system and I want to be able to track when the users clocked in and clocked out as well as be able to pull a report of hours worked between date 1 and date 2.

My thought was when they logged in to set a sorted set with the key being their name the score being the timestamp when they logged in and the value will be blank. Then when they sign out I will set the value to the timestamp of the logged out time. Then I could pull reports based off the score. Is this practical and/or is there a better way to do it instead?

Edit (from comment):

Using a sorted set you can do a query sort of speak by fetching all the records with the score that's greater then the starting timestamp.

So for ease of use say the users login timestamps are 50, 100, 150 and 200 you can tell redis to give you all the data for records whose timestamp is greater then 100 and it would return the last 2 records.

It can easily be done in mysql or some other database, but I believe it can easily be done in `redis` as well.

For me server resources are crucial so using `redis` over `mysql` is a big plus.

Comment: In redis: no. You can't query redis, you can only get keys. There are other databases more suitable for this problem.

Comment: No offense but that wasn't really the question. Using a sorted set you can do a query sort of speak by fetching all the records with the score that's greater then the starting timestamp. So for ease of use say the users login timestamps are 50, 100, 150 and 200 you can tell redis to give you all the data for records whos timestamp is greater then 100 and it would return the last 2 records. 

I can easily do it in mysql or some other database, but I believe it can easily be done in redis as well. For my server resources are crucial so using redis over mysql is a big pro for me.

Comment: That's a practical and simple way IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly record punch in and out times. But you can't pull a report on hours. Those you will have to calculate in your client side code by pulling the last login and last logout and doing the math. And of course handling cases of missed logins or log outs.

You don't "pull reports" from Redis, you store and retrieve data. There are many ways to store the data but your question is too broad.